# DnD in Cocoa: Finder vs own program

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, finder

ALL,

Reading the `Apple` documentation I don't see an answer to one simple thing:

How do I differentiate between `DnD` from `Finder/Desktop` and `DnD` from my own program?

It does talk about implementing `DnD`, but it says that you need to implement `DragMove` on the sender, which is impossible if `DnD` is initiated from `Finder`.

Now there was a question here on SO, which said that `Finder` does put the file name instead of content into the pasteboard, but it does not help since I want to be able to do `DnD` from both my own program and `Finder`. But I need to somehow differentiate between them.

Any helps/pointers will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: info.draggingSource may be what you're looking for…